# Email Frequency Capping in Marketing Cloud Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect, exclusion-script

I want to do the **Frequency Capping** to those Emails which are sent/triggered from the Marketing Cloud Connect.

I know that we can add the **exclusion Script** to the Journey Emails, Content Builder Emails,  Automation Studio Emails and Triggered Emails to applied the Frequency Capping at the send time.

Similarly, is there any good way to add the Frequency Capping while sending emails from the Marketing Cloud Connect?

Answer (score 4):

You can create an initial Auto Suppression data extension and then use the API to add a query that targets it.  (You have to use the API to create the query since you can't select the Auto Suppression data extension as the target through the interface.)

The query (or queries) could include criteria based on aggregated sends counts by subscriber as [@Lukas](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/36623/lukas-lunow) suggested.

Automating the query his works well for account-wide frequency suppression.

Comment: Hey, @Adam thanks for your time and response, okay I'll check using the API.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to build a custom solution, where a Data Extension built on querying your _sent data view will keep track on how many emails a consumer has received over the last X days, and you then use AmpScript in your email to validate against that Data Extension whether this recipient indeed is allowed to be emailed or not. In the case where the email should not be sent, you can use [RaiseError](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/raiseerror.htm) function to stop the email, but continue the job for the next subscriber.

This approach is indeed universal, and as it is not linked to a specific method, it can be utilised in triggered sends, guided sends, journeys etc.

Comment: I would not recommend this approach as RaiseError() count as a send and should only be used for exclusion. The exclusion should be done before the send.

Comment: Valid point, @JeremyGarcia - thanks for bringing it up! I guess the quality of my answers is proportional to the number of days left till weekend.

Comment: Thank you @Lukas for your time and response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait steps in Journey Builder, with some custom setup:

Let's say you don't want to send more than One email per week to subscribers.

**Create & maintain a DE:**
Query the _sent data view to grab all the subscriber keys that were communicated to in the past week, include also the latest send date for each. Add 7 days to the latest send date and include this as a third column. Push above Three attributes into a DE, and set subscriber key column to subscriber key (you may also need to connect this DE to the contact key in Data Designer, subscriber key from _sent = contact key). Automate this process to refresh daily.

**Wait step in Journey Builder**
Once you have the above DE automated and maintained,  then you can configure a wait step in journey builder to only let through subscribers whom have the above third column in the past, otherwise wait until that is true.

Comment: Is there any way to only count commercial sends towards frequency capping. We are using Default Commercial and Default Transactional as send classifications?